# Signature box not displaying correctly in landscape mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimage, cgrect

I have a view controller that creates an image frame ( a white box) where the user can sign their name. In portrait mode on the ipad this works just fine but when I go to sign from landscape mode the box appears on the bottom left side of the screen, not in the center like it should.

I've used the code below, any helps or suggestions would be appreciated.

```
@interface PropertyOwnerSignatureViewController ()

@end

@implementation PropertyOwnerSignatureViewController

@synthesize mySignatureImage;
@synthesize lastContactPoint1, lastContactPoint2, currentPoint;
@synthesize imageFrame;
@synthesize fingerMoved;
@synthesize navbarHeight;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self                             = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
     name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
     object:[UIDevice currentDevice]];


    //    //set the title of the navigation view
    [self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Sign here"];

        self.view.backgroundColor        = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

     //get reference to the navigation frame to calculate navigation bar height
    CGRect navigationframe           = [[self.navigationController navigationBar] frame];
    navbarHeight                     = navigationframe.size.height;
    //

    //    //create a frame for our signature capture based on whats remaining
    imageFrame                       = CGRectMake(self.view.center.x,
                                                  self.view.center.y,
                                                  self.view.frame.size.width,
                                                  self.view.frame.size.height/2.5);



    //    //allocate an image view and add to the main view
    mySignatureImage                 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nil];
    mySignatureImage.frame           = imageFrame;
    mySignatureImage.center          = self.view.center;
    mySignatureImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:mySignatureImage];
    AppDelegate *appDelegate =
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if(appDelegate.imagePhSignature)
    {
        mySignatureImage.image = appDelegate.imagePhSignature;
    }


}

- (void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note
{
    UIDevice * device = note.object;
    mySignatureImage.center          = self.view.center;

    switch(device.orientation)
    {
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
            /* start special animation */
            break;

        case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            /* start special animation */
            break;

        default:
            break;
    };
}
```

Comment: did you want the signature view in pr=ortaiot and landscape mode same?

Comment: yes the box should be the same centered in both

Answer (score 0):

replace this lines

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate =
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

//    //create a frame for our signature capture based on whats remaining
imageFrame                       = CGRectMake(appDelegate.window.center.x,
                                              appDelegate.window.center.y,
                                              appDelegate.window.size.width,
                                              appDelegate.window.bounds.size.width/1.5);
```

Comment: I'm getting an error as property window not found on object of type app delegate

Comment: in your appdelgate window name is different?

Comment: no it is just window, under @property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

Comment: thn you get it. May be some spelling mistake there